# calling function with parameters and with return from bashoperator

Tags: airflow

I have this

```
BashOperator(
        task_id=( dag_id + "_extract" ).lower(),
        bash_command="python /usr/local/airflow/txd-mfp-extract.py {{ params.query }} {{ params.file }} {{ params.monday }} {{ params.sunday }}",
        on_success_callback=on_success_alert,
        on_failure_callback=on_failure_alert,
        params={
            'query': query_name,
            'file': file_name,
            'monday': get_monday,
            'sunday': get_sunday,
        },
        dag=dag)
```

and `get_monday` and `get_sunday` are function hta return values for de `bash_command`, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call that function `get_monday()` instead of `get_monday`. And `get_sunday()` instead of `get_sunday`.

```
BashOperator(
        task_id=( dag_id + "_extract" ).lower(),
        bash_command="python /usr/local/airflow/txd-mfp-extract.py {{ params.query }} {{ params.file }} {{ params.monday }} {{ params.sunday }}",
        on_success_callback=on_success_alert,
        on_failure_callback=on_failure_alert,
        params={
            'query': query_name,
            'file': file_name,
            'monday': get_monday(),
            'sunday': get_sunday(),
        },
        dag=dag)
```